# Linux Lua: Permission denied on https request

Tags: linux, sockets, https, lua, permission-denied

I've been trying to send a https request using ssl.https library in Lua, however no matter what url I give, I alway get permission denied and no other values like headers, etc. The linux I am using is CentOS Linux version 7.

Here is the example code:

```lua
    local httpsocket = require("socket.http")
    local httpssocket = require ("ssl.https")
    local ltn12 = require("ltn12")

    local res, code, response_headers, status = httpssocket.request("https://www.google.com")
    
    module:log("info","%s %s",code.."",response_headers);
```

The code itself is part of a prosody plugin and the last line in this example prints this out:

```
    permission denied <nil>
```

My question is how do I fix this issue so that I can access the page?

EDIT: It seem that the problem might be the user that the service is run under and needs root privilages otherwise it throws ACCES error for ports lower than 1024. Does anyone know what to do in this case?

Comment: Restrictions with ports lower than 1024 is related to `listen` but not with `connect`. This may be more related with firewall or loading ssl library restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

So... after attempting fix this issue again, I finally found the solution. If you are having trouble with services not being able to send http/https request on centOS, there is a single command that has to be run to fix this issue:

```bash
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
```

For those who might have similar issues but not quite the same as me, look into the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for anything related to your program, process, service, etc. then use this command:

```bash
grep <pattern_to_match_specific_log> /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
```

This will give you a reason why it failed and how to fix it